# Get Compiled Select gives only initial table CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

Hello guys getCompiled Select in CodeIgniter returns only
Select * from tablename don't have any joins and wheres

```
if (!empty($requestArr)) {
        $this->data['listings'] = $listingModel
            ->join('countries', 'listings.country_id=countries.country_id', 'LEFT')
            ->join('states', 'listings.state_id=states.state_id', 'LEFT')
            ->join('cities', 'listings.city_id=cities.city_id', 'LEFT')
            ->join('purposes', 'listings.purpose_id=purposes.purpose_id', 'LEFT')
            ->join('sub_purposes', 'listings.sub_purpose_id=sub_purposes.sub_purpose_id', 'LEFT')
            ->join('types', 'listings.type_id=types.type_id', 'LEFT')
            ->join('sub_types', 'listings.sub_type_id=sub_types.sub_type_id', 'LEFT')
            ->orLike('area',"%".$requestArr['area']."%")
            ->orWhere('listings.city_id', $requestArr['city_id'])
            ->orWhere('listings.state_id', $requestArr['city_id'])
            ->where('land_area', $requestArr['pSize'])
            ->where('land_unit', $requestArr['area_unit'])
            ->where('bedrooms', $requestArr['bedrooms'])
            ->where('bedrooms', $requestArr['bedrooms'])
            ->where('listings.purpose_id', $requestArr['purpose_id'])
            ->where('listings.type_id', $requestArr['type_id'])
            ->orderBy('listings.created_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(6);
        echo $listingModel->getCompiledSelect();
        echo json_encode($this->data['listings']);
```

I want to print the whole generated query but only give result in the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: *paginate()* can't be printed with `getCompiledSelect` because CI4 handle the pagination query dynamically afterwards. If you want to print your select query you should try to replace `->paginate(6);` with `->getCompiledSelect()` and print `$this->data['listings']`

Comment: Thanks. This was a small change and worked

Comment: @SyedSuhaibZia as a small note, you don't need to pass `%` to `orLike()` because it will already surround the string for you. Please see here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html